# Add trailing space to list of strings

Tags: python, string, list, whitespace, concatenation

I have a list of strings like this:

```
my_list = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,', 'consectetur adipiscing elit. ', 'Mauris id enim nisi, ullamcorper malesuada magna.']
```

I want to basically combine these items into one readable string. My logic is as follows:

```
If the list item does not end with a space, add one
otherwise, leave it alone
Then combine them all into one string.
```

I was able to accomplish this a few different ways.

Using a list comprehension:

```
message = ["%s " % x if not x.endswith(' ') else x for x in my_list]
messageStr = ''.join(message)
```

Spelling it out (I think this is a bit more readable):

```
for i, v in enumerate(my_list):
    if not v.endswith(' '):
        my_list[i] = "%s " % v
messageStr = ''.join(my_list)
```

My question is, is there an easier, "more sane" way of accomplishing this?

Comment: What is not 'sane' about this?

Comment: Well, it's not exactly insane per se, but I could tell I was making things more difficult. Luckily Nolen found a good solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> my_list = ['Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet,', 'consectetur adipiscing elit. ', 'Mauris id en
im nisi, ullamcorper malesuada magna.']
>>> ' '.join(string.strip() for string in my_list)
'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Mauris id enim nisi, ullamcorper
 malesuada magna.'
```

Comment: Thank you! That makes a lot more sense. One question, why use rstrip() instead of strip()?

Comment: I originally used strip, but you had said that you were dealing with strings that "ended" in a space so I figured we only needed to strip off spaces on the right side / I didn't want to remove spaces on the left that were important.  If I was wrong I'll gladly change it to strip.

Comment: In my script, I am getting these strings from a database (each row has part of the message). From what I've seen so far, the data is all kinds of messy. I think I'll be safe and use strip(), since the join should take care of spacing out the sentences after strip().

Comment: You should use a generator expression instead of a list comprehension to avoid making the temporary list. Just leave the `[]` out of the join

Comment: Reverted back to strip.  Thanks for the tip @gnibbler, you are always on top of these things :D

Answer (score 1):

You could simply the list comprehension a little by using `strip`:

```
' '.join([x.strip() for x in list])
```

It's also best not to call your list "list" as that is a built-in.

Comment: Good idea, I've changed the variable name in my original question. Thanks.